# Can somebody explain me this script line

Tags: bash, shell, aix

Can somebody explain me this script line from an AIX bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
touch /tmp/</.D2D
```

i suppose that the lines (items) in the File /.D2D will be read an the files will be touched under the tmp dir:

when the content of the /.D2D file is

```
file1
file2
```

then following will be executed:

```
touch /tmp/file1
touch /tmp/file2
```

### or this one:

```
#!/bin/bash
PM=text
FILELIST=/tmp/$PM.</.filelist
```

Here the FILELIST will be an array with the line of the /.filelist concatenated with /tmp/text.line1OfFilelistfile and /tmp/text.line2OfFilelistfile and so on ...

Is my understanding right?
Thanks

Comment: Ok, the points of the guys who answered, showed me the right way. The examples above are not working. The script file, which i am currently analazing has Format / Syntax errors inside. So the "</" has to be replaced by "$$" Now it comes clear what it is and what it does.

Answer (score 1):

Touch doesn't read from Stdin, so the input redirection has no other effect than bash checking the existence of the file to be redirected. Hence the code is roughly equivalent to

```
if [[ -f /.DSD ]]
then
  touch /tmp
else
  echo bash: /.DSD: No such file or directory 1>&2
fi
```

So far the theory. In practice, I guess there is a typo in the line.

Comment: Thanks for the answere. And what do you think about the second one?

Comment: Well, it's exactly the same problem. Input redirection doesn't make sense when assigning to a variable....

Answer (score 0):

The [man page for touch](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_71/com.ibm.aix.cmds5/touch.htm) doesn't mention that the touch command ever reads anything from stdin. Therefore the commands do not touch any file from the list, they only touch those files given directly on their command lines.

To confirm this, run the bash script with a tool like strace, ktrace, truss. They log out all system calls that happen.

Comment: Thanks for the answere. And what do you think about the second one?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the points of the guys who answered, showed me the right way. The examples above are not working. The script file, which i am currently analazing has Format / Syntax errors inside. So the "